# What type of object is a gitlab runner job?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, newrelic

I am tasked with building a new relic chart to show gitlab runner job count over time.
I am trying to determine what type of object is a gitlab runner job. Is is a deployment, a pod or a statefulset?

Any assistance with being able to visualize gitlab runner pods in new relic would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Kubernetes executor for GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html)":

> The Kubernetes executor, when used with GitLab CI, connects to the Kubernetes API in the cluster creating **a Pod for each GitLab CI Job**.
>
> This Pod is made up of, at the very least:
>
> - a build container,
> - a helper container, and
> - an additional container for each service defined in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` or `config.toml` files.

Since those are pods, you should see them in a [NewRelic Kubernetes cluster explorer](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/kubernetes-pixie/kubernetes-integration/understand-use-data/kubernetes-cluster-explorer/).